# Upgrading Apache Flink Kubernetes Cluster from 1.16 to 1.17: Potential Breaking Changes?

Tags: apache-flink

I am currently running an Apache Flink Kubernetes cluster on version 1.16 and considering upgrading to version 1.17. Before proceeding, I want to ensure a smooth transition and avoid any unexpected issues.

Are there any known breaking changes or major considerations when upgrading the Apache Flink Kubernetes cluster from version 1.16 to 1.17?

I have reviewed the release notes and documentation for Apache Flink, but I'm looking for insights from others who have already performed this upgrade. Any tips, gotchas, or best practices related to this upgrade would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiples ways to run Apache Flink on Kubernetes that are worthwhile to distinguish (based on the submission path), most notably:

1. Via the vanilla [standalone integration](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/),
2. Via the [Flink Kubernetes Operator](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-kubernetes-operator-docs-main/).

I have explicit experience of upgrading from 1.16 to 1.17 via the Kubernetes Operator and application mode, which went completely smooth. I would expect the same for most other applications, but please do you own validation too.